# 100mbit over 1Gbit router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have a 1Gbit ethernet cable that is attached to router Asus RT-N18U and then 1Gbit ethernet cable that goes from the router to my laptop. I am sure that my laptop's network card supports 1Gbit connections because when I plug the cable from the wall (omitting router) right into my laptop's port it is 1Gbit connection. When the cable goes through the router (which also supports 1Gbit) the connection is right under 100Mbit. I am also sure that all of my ethernet cables support 1Gbit speed because I checked them. Is it a problem with router configuration? I cannot locate the problem.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms - Reread the question; when he bypasses the router, he says he gets a 1GB cx.

Comment: thanks for the correction Jeff, If this is the case maybe some throttling set up in the router configuration? did you try going into the router settings and snooping around to see if there are any things that are preventing it from pushing the 1gb speeds?

Comment: Does the router's management UI, or its WAN port status LEDs, tell you what link speed it's autonegotiating on its WAN port?

Comment: Are there any other cables plugged in to the router? If so, test speed after unplugging all except the laptop.

Comment: Have you tried different ports on the router? What does the operating system report the link speed as?

Comment: RickwhoPrograms, Spiff - I checked everything in the router management interface (also I am not quite sure what do all these options mean) and the speed remains the same. The router doesn't have any speed LED indicator (you can google this model). DrMoishe Pippik - There is only this cable plugged to the router, but... @Tim_Stewart - This was it! Plugged my laptop to another port on the router and know I have 1Gbit connection!  Thank you all, guys! I was sure I checked everything but I missed that.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else searching. Changing the port in use on the router fixed the issue, indicating a bad/failing port.